# Changing icon after compiling (Python)

Tags: python, icons, pyinstaller

I'm using Python 2.7, and pyinstaller in order to make an exe.

Everything works just fine, but the exe file's icon is the PyInstaller icon.

**Is there a way to change the icon?**

I found this : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/192592-making-an-exe-file-with-pyinstaller/

But don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, try:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico app.py
```

Found in [this](https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script) guide. A quick Google search will lead you to tons of .ico files if you need one.

Comment: I did PyInstaller --onefile --icon=favicon.ico main.spec but it's not working